# Consuming a web services MEX endpoint outside of Windows

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap, wsdl, endpoint

I want to access a Windows-hosted web service. I have no control over the service or its configuration. Using Visual Studio I can create a Service Reference pointing at the endpoint `https://example.com/PylonServices/AddressServiceEndpoint.svc/mex` and all the methods appear.

I want to write a client to access this service using a Linux-based scripting language, e.g., PHP. However, tt appears that the service does not make the WSDL file for the service available via HTTP, only MEX.

How can I get PHP to create a SOAP client when the service only provides a MEX endpoint? I am happy to use another scripting language (e.g., Perl, Ruby, Python, etc.) if need be.